# On the spectral decomposition of a positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, physics, diagonalization, positive-semidefinite

[Nielsen & Chuang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Information) (978-1-107-00217-3) state the following on page 101:

> A positive $2^n\times 2^n$ matrix $\rho$ (that can be seen as a linear
> mapping from $\mathbb{C}^{2^n}$ to $\mathbb{C}^{2^n}$) has a spectral
> decomposition
>
> $$\rho= \sum_i \lambda_i |i\rangle\langle i|$$
>
> where the vectors $|i\rangle\in\mathbb{C}^{2^n}$ are orthogonal and
> $\lambda_i$ a non negative real eigenvalue of $\rho$.

Does this mean, that there is always a orthonormal basis $|j\rangle$ of $\mathbb{C}^{2^n}$ such that $\rho$ can be written as

$$\rho= \sum_j \lambda_j |j\rangle\langle j|?$$
Is Nielsen and Chuangs way of putting it totally identical to my thought? Am I making up a difference where there is (practically) none?

For me, one still needs a proof for this - but I can't put it in precise words: Obviously one could find a $\rho$ such that the used $|j\rangle$ (the ones with $\lambda_j\neq 0$) give a basis. But to me it is necessary to say *why*. That's where I am stuck.

Comment: Are you looking for a proof of the spectral theorem or how that theorem applies the above structure to $\rho$?

Comment: I want to know if the spectral theorem says that the $|i\rangle$'s are an ONB - this would lead me to believe, that Nielsen just doesn't verbalize the spectral theorem precisely enough here. If the spectral theorem doesn't include a ONB, I am looking for a proof for my thought, given in the question above. You see - there are many different versions of the spectral theorem, at least I am quite confused with different (quite similar but not qet exactly the same) explanations.

Comment: Yes, the spectral theorem says that there exists an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of $\rho$ -- see [Spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Hermitian_maps_and_Hermitian_matrices).

Comment: So Nielsen and Chuang do mean the spectral theorem - just kind of say it in a different way, right?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent -- you can show that they imply one another.

Comment: How do I show that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to show the following two statements are equivalent:

1. For any positive semidefinite matrix $\rho$ there exists an orthonormal basis $|i\rangle$ and nonnegative $\lambda_i$ such that
   $$
   \rho = \sum_i \lambda_i |i \rangle \langle i |
   $$
2. For any positive semidefinite matrix $\rho$ its eigenvectors form an orthonormal basis and it's eigenvalues are nonnegative.

Proof:
$1 \implies 2$

It is clear from the decomposition that
$$
\rho |i \rangle  = \lambda_i |i \rangle
$$
so $|i\rangle$ are the eigenvectors with corresponding eigenvalues of $\rho$ moreover by (1) they form an orthonormal basis.

$2 \implies 1$.

In the orthonormal basis $|i\rangle$ a general matrix $\rho$ can be written as
$$
\rho = \sum_{ij} c_{ij} |i \rangle \langle j |\,.
$$
As $|i\rangle$ are the eigenvectors of $\rho$ we know that we must have $\rho |i\rangle = \lambda_i |i\rangle$. And because the eigenvalues form an orthonormal basis we therefore need that
$$
\delta_{kl} \lambda_l = \langle k | \rho |l \rangle  =  \langle k | \sum_{ij}  c_{ij} |i\rangle \langle j| |l \rangle = c_{kl}
$$
and therefore
$$
c_{ij} = \begin{cases} 0 \qquad &\text{ if }i \neq j \\
\lambda_i \qquad &\text{ if } i = j
\end{cases} 
$$
therefore
$$
\rho = \sum_{i} \lambda_i |i \rangle \langle i|\,.
$$

Comment: In 2: How do I know that the eigenvectors form an orthonormal basis? Nielsen and Chuang only say, that they are orthonormal...

Comment: Looking at the book they have a proof of the spectral decomposition in Box 2.2 (theorem 2.1) page 72 in the version I have access to. In 2. I am using the statement on the wiki page for the spectral theorem.